# Data formatting and manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to format data from a text file to a specific format. My data file contains more than 120000 rows but I have posted here truncated data. The data file has R, L, G, C data for different frequencies (here 3 frequency in 3 rows). The file has only 2 columns 1st column is "Freq" and 2nd column is either one of the RLGC data. Now I want to manipulate the data to another format (Let's say, the target .txt). here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eg6mc4030i3dui1/data_in.txt?dl=0) of data. I want to convert it to target file like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf9ghkhwb4timkb/target.txt?dl=0).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame from csv with columns f and v 
df = pd.read_csv('data_in.txt', sep="\s+", names=['freq','v'])
#df = df.astype(float).convert_objects()

#boolean mask for identify columns of new df   
m = df['v'].str.endswith('R', 'L', 'G', 'C')
#new column by replace NaNs by forward filling
df['g'] = df['v'].where(m).ffill()
#get original ordering for new columns
cols = df['g'].unique()
#remove rows with same values in v and g columns
df = df[df['v'] != df['g']]
#reshape by pivoting with change ordering of columns by reindex
df = df.pivot('freq', 'g', 'v').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reindex(columns=cols).reset_index()

df.columns = [x.replace('R','R1:1').replace('L','L1:1').replace('G','G1:1').replace('C','C1:1') for x in df.columns]
df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t')
```

But it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: wrapper3() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Can anyone help me to format it into target file.

Now I need another formatting other than target file. I need to format into like "[**target_2.txt**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/azerja8foicqm4z/target_2.txt?dl=0)". This is another unusual type of format that is also needed. You can see that each of the R1:1, L1:1, G1:1 and C1:1 data now seem like a block of array (though not an array). If you look closely, for `freq`, it should names as `FORMAT Freq`, then a `tab`, then `:`, then again a `tab` and then `R1:1`. If you see, it will be like - `FORMAT Freq+tab+:+tab+R1:1`. Then a `new line`, then `2 tabs`, then `L1:1`. Then again a `new line`, then `2 tabs`, then `G1:1`. And, finally the same for `C1:1`. After that a *blank line*, then follows the 1st row of data, 2nd row of data and continues. The data values will be according to the header line.

How to do that 2nd target file?

I am using Spyder 3.2.6 where python 3.6.4 64-bit is embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use `str.endswith` this way. For what you seem to look for, I would say `str.contains` is a better solution where you look for R or L or ... such as:

```
m = df['v'].str.contains('R|L|G|C')
```

Then your code until `pivot`. I got an error at the `pivot` line caused by rows with `nan`, so you may need a `dropna` and you can `rename` the columns at the same time:

```
df = (df.dropna().pivot('freq', 'g', 'v').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reindex(columns=cols).reset_index()
        .rename(columns={col:'{}1:1'.format(col) for col in cols}))
```

and `df` looks like:

```
       freq      R1:1      L1:1      G1:1      C1:1
0  0.00E+00  2.66E+00  3.00E-07  2.76E-16  1.58E-10
1  1.00E+06  2.89E+00  3.10E-07  1.72E-05  1.46E-10
2  2.00E+06  2.98E+00  3.13E-07  3.43E-05  1.45E-10
3  3.00E+06  3.07E+00  3.15E-07  5.15E-05  1.44E-10
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. I have updated the question for another unusual formatting which is most important. Can you check on that? I have uploaded the 2nd target file as well.

Comment: It worked but while my data is big enough and the step size is decreasing between data then the data is not monotonic while saving in the new dataframe. I have created another question. Can you look at it? Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878093/formatting-the-data-which-increases-monotonically-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `pivot` after some initial clean-up.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data_in.txt', sep='\s+', names=['freq','v'])

# Determine where `'freq'` occurs
mask = df.freq == 'freq'

# Create the column headers you want for each measurement
df.loc[mask, 'col_names'] = df.loc[mask, 'v']
df['col_names'] = df.col_names.ffill() + '1:1'

# Pivot to desired output
df = df.loc[~mask].pivot(index = 'freq', 
                         columns ='col_names', 
                         values = 'v').reset_index()
df.columns.name=None
df = df.astype('float')
```

Output:

```
        freq          C1:1          G1:1          L1:1      R1:1
0        0.0  1.580132e-10  2.763283e-16  2.997629e-07  2.661409
1  1000000.0  1.459912e-10  1.716549e-05  3.096696e-07  2.892461
2  2000000.0  1.447848e-10  3.434434e-05  3.130131e-07  2.981991
3  3000000.0  1.440792e-10  5.152409e-05  3.151563e-07  3.066247
```

Comment: Good idea to rename what is going to be the column names during the `ffill` :) +1

Comment: thanks a lot. It also worked. I have updated the question for another unusual formatting which is most important. Can you check on that? I have uploaded the 2nd target file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with regular string manipulations like this:

```
#open file
filename='data_in.txt'
file = open(filename,'r')
fileData=file.read()
file.close() 

#remove carriage returns
fileData=fileData.replace("\r","")


chunkNumber=0
data=[]

for chunk in fileData.split("\n\n\n"):
    chunkNumber+=1
    chunkType=chunk.split("\n")[0].split("\t")[1]
    firstData=["freq"]
    thisData=["%s:%s"%(chunkType,chunkNumber)]
    for line in chunk.split("\n")[1:]:
        entries=line.split("    ")
        thisData.append(entries[1])
        firstData.append(entries[0])
    data.append(thisData)
data=[firstData]+data

string=""
for j in range(5):
    for k in data:
        string+=k[j]+"\t"
    string=string[:-1]+"\n"

filename='output.txt'
file = open(filename,'w')
file.writelines(string)
file.close()
```