# Formatting the data which increases monotonically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have formatted the data according to the need. Now my final data or dataframe is not monotonically increasing whereas the input data is increasing monotonically according to the 1st column field (`freq`). Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvvj3ch8wqxg5si/Data_input_truncated.txt?dl=0) for `Data_input_truncated.txt`. My python code is in the below:

```
import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame from csv with columns f and v 
df = pd.read_csv('Data_input.txt', sep="\s+", names=['freq','v'])

#boolean mask for identify columns of new df   
m = df['v'].str.endswith(')')
#new column by replace NaNs by forward filling
df['g'] = df['v'].where(m).ffill()
#get original ordering for new columns
cols = df['g'].unique()
#remove rows with same values in v and g columns
df = df[df['v'] != df['g']]
#reshape by pivoting with change ordering of columns by reindex
df = df.pivot('freq', 'g', 'v').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reindex(columns=cols).reset_index()

df.columns = [x.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',',':') for x in df.columns]
df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t')
```

Now the created `target.txt` is not monotonic. Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk9g4a3hbcys89v/target.txt?dl=0) for `target.txt`. How can I make it monotonic before saving as a file?

I am using Spyder 3.2.6 (Anaconda) where python 3.6.4 64-bit is embedded.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, I have shortened the data and also code. Is that fine now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your data is `str` and not a `float`, and while pivoting, it is reorder with alphabetical order. One option could be to change the type of the `freq` column to float, and then if the formatting as scientific number is important, you can set the `float_format` parameter during `to_csv`:

```
### same code before
#remove rows with same values in v and g columns
df = df[df['v'] != df['g']]
# convert to float
df['freq']= df['freq'].astype(float)

#reshape by pivoting with change ordering of columns by reindex
df = df.pivot('freq', 'g', 'v').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reindex(columns=cols).reset_index()

df.columns = [x.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',',':') for x in df.columns]
df.to_csv('target.txt', index=False, sep='\t', float_format='%.17E' ) # add float_format='%.17E'
```

Note `float_format='%.17E'` means scientific notation with 17 numbers after the `.` as in your input, but you can change this number to anyone you want if they are not important.

EDIT: I get this result in target.txt (first 5 rows and 3 columns)

```
freq    R1:1    R1:2
0.00000000000000000E+00 4.07868642871600962E0   3.12094533520232087E-13
1.00000000000000000E+06 4.43516799439728793E0   4.58503433913467795E-3
2.00000000000000000E+06 4.54224931058591253E0   1.21517855438593236E-2
3.00000000000000000E+06 4.63952376349496909E0   2.10017318391844077E-2
4.00000000000000000E+06 4.74002677709486608E0   3.05258806632440871E-2
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked partially as you said. It is monotonically formatting only after the decimal point, but not as a whole number. How to change it to float for the whole number? Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p1eredlygdg2yf/target_new.txt?dl=0) of my `target_new.txt` file for your convenience.

Comment: @aguntuk the `target_new.txt` seems to be the same than the `target.txt`. can you tell me where to look for the difference, I don't see it?

Comment: after `1.00000000000000000E6`, it should be `2.00000000000000000E6` then `3.00000000000000000E6` but instead it is `1.00000000000000000E7`,  `1.10000000000000009E7`...`2.00000000000000000E6` comes after `1.89999999999999991E7`

Comment: I don't know what do you mean it by it was before. The original data `Data_input.txt` is monotonic. After the data manipulation as it is non-monotonic when I use this data for input in my circuit in another program (Cadence) it asks for monotonic data and returns me an error as the data is not monotonic.

Comment: @aguntuk Sorry, by before I meant in the link to `target.txt` you provided in the question. What I don't understand is why the order is not good in your result. I tried with your data and I get the monotonic incremental value for the freq as you can see in my edit

Comment: @aguntuk just to be sure, have you seen this line of code `df['freq']= df['freq'].astype(float)` in my answer, it's not fully obvious as it's in the middle of your code, so just want to be sure that is not the problem?

Comment: Yeah...I was just going to comment about that and you wrote. The thing is while copying the code, I missed it. How I don't know! Now it is working....thanks a lot for helping man....btw...I cannot tag you somehow with @Ben.T!!

Comment: @aguntuk good then :) I don't know why you can't tag me, I guess I get a notification anyway because it's my answer while you might not if I don't tag you... good question ;)